# Custom Push Notification Design

Tags: ios, swift, remote-notifications

I have implemented Remote push notification using firebase. Notification comes successfully. But it has the same design pattern. Is it possible to change the design of those notification and if Yes then how??

Any reading links and answers will help.

Comment: Did you saw any other app change notification design?

Comment: like gmail app. It is having sender name in one line that too bold, after that subject in another line written in bold then in next line some of content of mail in plain text

Comment: Yes you can re-design your notifications. Here is a tutorial that show how to proceed : https://medium.com/@lucasgoesvalle/custom-push-notification-with-image-and-interactions-on-ios-swift-4-ffdbde1f457 I reckon that overall the notification can behave like a custom ViewControllers.

Comment: In gmail it sis just a title and subtitle

Comment: @Olympiloutre thanks putting me in this article again. My bad I dint gave it time to read it properly earlier. One of my issue is solved. Reading this further for design problem.

Comment: @RateM this is the complete overview of what you can do with notifications. My answer got downvoted and deleted but @ Kelvin Tran send the same link so overall it solves your answer

Comment: Yes it looks full.. Can you tell me how will I send notification from firebase just as the writer is framing in NWPusher?